# AppendStreamTableSink doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node Join(joinType=[InnerJoin]

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-batch

When I use **Flink SQL** to execute the following statement, the error is reported as follows：

**Request**

Group the data in the user_behavior_kafka_table according to the `user_id` field, and then take out the piece of data with the largest value of the `ts` field in each group

**excute sql**

```
SELECT user_id,item_id,ts FROM user_behavior_kafka_table AS a 
WHERE ts = (select max(b.ts) 
FROM user_behavior_kafka_table AS b 
WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id );
```

**Flink version**

1.11.2

**error message**

```
AppendStreamTableSink doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node Join(joinType=[InnerJoin], where=[((user_id = user_id0) AND (ts = EXPR$0))], select=[user_id, item_id, ts, user_id0, EXPR$0], leftInputSpec=[NoUniqueKey], rightInputSpec=[JoinKeyContainsUniqueKey])
```

**Job deploy**

On Yarn

**Table Message**

- user_behavior_kafka_table   ***data from consumer kafka topic***

{"user_id":"aaa","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"aaa access item at","ts":100}

{"user_id":"ccc","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"ccc access item at","ts":200}

{"user_id":"ccc","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"ccc access item at","ts":300}

{"user_id":"bbb","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"bbb access item at","ts":200}

{"user_id":"aaa","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"aaa access item at","ts":200}

{"user_id":"aaa","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"aaa access item at","ts":400}

{"user_id":"ccc","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"ccc access item at","ts":400}

{"user_id":"vvv","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"vvv access item at","ts":200}

{"user_id":"bbb","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"bbb access item at","ts":300}

{"user_id":"aaa","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"aaa access item at","ts":300}

{"user_id":"ccc","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"ccc access item at","ts":100}

{"user_id":"bbb","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"bbb access item at","ts":100}

- user_behavior_hive_table   ***Expected result***

{"user_id":"aaa","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"aaa access item at","ts":400}

{"user_id":"bbb","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"bbb access item at","ts":300}

{"user_id":"ccc","item_id":"11-222-333","comment":"ccc access item at","ts":400}

{"user_id":"vvv","item_id":"11-222-334","comment":"vvv access item at","ts":200}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the results you expect from that query, it needs to be executed in batch mode. As a streaming query, the Flink SQL planner can't cope with it, and if it could, it would produce a stream of results, where the last result for each `user_id` would match the expected results, but there would be additional, intermediate results.

For example, for user aaa, these results would appear:

```
aaa 11-222-333 100
aaa 11-222-333 200
aaa 11-222-334 400
```

but the row where ts=300 would be skipped, since it was never the row with the max value for ts.

If you want to make this work in streaming mode, try reformulating it as a [top-n query](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/topn/):

```sql
SELECT user_id, item_id, ts FROM
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ts DESC) AS row_num
  FROM user_behavior_kafka_table)
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

I believe this should work, but I'm not in a position to easily test it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply！I have tested the solution you mentioned, and it works!